# gpsd service does not locate USB GPS

Tags: linux, kubuntu, gps

I have a BU-353S4 USB GPS receiver. I am running Kubuntu 18.04. When I manually run gpsd with `gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0`, it correctly identifies the device and gets a fix when one is available.

When I let `gpsd` run automatically, this doesn't work. It seems that gpsd does not find the device and does not try to open it.

If I add /dev/ttyUSB0 to `/etc/defaults/gpsd` and I run the service, then the GPS works. However, if I then disconnect the GPS and reconnects it, then the daemon does not locate it again.

My `/etc/defaults/gpsd` says:

```
# Default settings for the gpsd init script and the hotplug wrapper.

# Start the gpsd daemon automatically at boot time
START_DAEMON="true"

# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS=""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does a manual `sudo gpsdctl add /dev/ttyUSB0` correctly add the device?

Comment: Yes. And also some text to make the comment long enough.